# A word that means education away from self reliance

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that means: To deliberately educate the masses away from knowledge of self sustainability/self reliance. I heard this word some 10 years ago and can't remember what it was..

Comment: Capitalism.  (Seriously -- think about it.)

Answer (score 1):

Close, but no cigar:

**disenfranchise**

> Disfranchisement is also termed to the revocation of power or control of a particular individual, community or being to the natural amenity they are abound in; that is to deprive of a franchise, of a legal right, of some privilege or inherent immunity. –[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disfranchisement)

Usually, it has to do with voting:

dis·en·fran·chise /ˌdisənˈfran(t)SHīz/ verb –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=disenfranchise&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> **deprive (someone) of the right to vote.**
>       *"the law disenfranchised some 3,000 voters on the basis of a residence qualification"*
>   **deprived of power; marginalized.**
>           *"a hard core of kids who are disenfranchised and don't feel connected to the school"*
>   **deprive (someone) of a right or privilege.**
>   "a measure that would disenfranchise people from access to legal advice"

North Korea *disenfranchises* its citizens from just about everything.

Answer (score 1):

***Doublespeak*** (most likely coined by George Orwell in his book [*Nineteen Eighty-Four*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four)) is one such method of doing that which you've described. Here is the Wikipedia definition:

> [Doublespeak is language that deliberately disguises, distorts, or
>   reverses the meaning of words.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublespeak)

In many cases, doublespeak effectively amounts to feeding the masses trivia-masquerading-as-fact so as to deter them from educating themselves — or, as Edward S. Herman is quoted (from the same Wikipedia entry),

> "What is really important in the world of doublespeak is the ability to
>   lie, whether knowingly or unconsciously, and to get away with it; and
>   the ability to use lies and choose and shape facts selectively,
>   blocking out those that don’t fit an agenda or program."

Note that *obfuscation*, or the act of purposely confusing someone or -thing, is a key component of doublespeak.

Also of note is ***[disinformation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disinformation)***, which (again, as defined by Wikipedia) is

> "intentionally false or inaccurate information that is spread
>   deliberately. It is an act of deception and false statements to
>   convince someone of untruth."

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use the word "domesticate" since one definition is:

> **domesticate:** *to breed or train (an animal) to need and accept the care of human beings* **[[1]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/domesticate)**

Use of this word would, however, have a derogatory connotation in this context.